# Scalar subquery cannot have more than one column unless using SELECT AS STRUCT to build STRUCT values

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to write a query in BigQuery that select some rows based on row number and sum the columns.
In details, I have two tables: in `table1` there are for each id the number of rows of `table2` that I want to sum. An example of the two tables is below.

`table1`
[image: table1]

`table2`
[image: table2]

The desired output is:

| id | points1 | points2 | points3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 86 | 99 | 31 |
| b | 91 | 59 | 15 |
| c | 122 | 183 | 118 |

I created a UDF that tooks the 'neighbors' `n1`, `n2` and `n3` and sum the rows of `table2` whose row_num is in `n1`, `n2` and `n3`; then I recalled the UDF in my query below.

```
create temp function sum_points(neighbors array<int>) 
returns array<int>
as (sum((select * from `project.dataset.table2` where row_num in unnest(neighbors))));

with cte as (
  select id, array_agg(nn) as neighbors
  from `project.dataset.table1`, unnest([n1, n2, n3]) nn
  group by id
)
select id, sum_points(neighbors) from cte
```

However, I got the following error:

`Scalar subquery cannot have more than one column unless using SELECT AS STRUCT to build STRUCT values; failed to parse CREATE [TEMP] FUNCTION statement at [5:9]`

and it is not very clear to me what that means. I tried to replace the `select` inside `with` statement with `select struct<array<int>>` but it did not work.

Comment: How are you joining the tables?

Comment: @dikesh I want to use the values in `n1`, `n2`, `n3` of `table1` to select the rows in `table2`; for example, for id 'a' I want to select the rows 1,2,3 of `table2` and aggregate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better option would be to join tables and do aggregate.

You can join tables based on `row_num` from `table2` and `n1`, `n2`, `n3` from `table1` as below.

```
SELECT
  id,
  SUM(points1) AS points1,
  SUM(points2) AS points2,
  SUM(points3) AS points3
FROM table1 JOIN table2
ON row_num in (n1, n2, n3)
GROUP BY id
```

Output of the query:

| id | points1 | points2 | points3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 86 | 99 | 31 |
| c | 122 | 183 | 118 |
| b | 91 | 59 | 15 |